# Не могу понять в чем ошибка моего кода

Tags: c#

Не могу понять в чем ошибка в условном операторе, вроде все правильно
[image]

Comment: Две строчки после `if` должны быть внутри `{...}`.

Comment: Будет лучше, если вы код не картинкой вставите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли поставить `{...}` после условия `if`

```
  if (input > 500 && inputProcent < 50) 
  {
      result = inputPrice * divison;
      Console.WriteLine(result);
  }
```